# Как вызвать функцию из одного компонента в другом?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spa

Что бы не делать простынь с кодом я выложил 2 компонента в Gist

Собственно есть 2 компонента [List](https://gist.github.com/swartex/07a7d8e389c165ca604403680e744ae7) и [Modal](https://gist.github.com/swartex/db2dbb6fde8ca84b134ef5374a258a02)
В компоненте Лист есть функция `submit` которая сохраняет изменения или новый элемент в массиве.

```
submit: function (item) {
    let self = this;
    if (item.id == null
      || item.name == null
      || item.old == null
      || item.email == null
      || !self.checkEmailValid(item.email)) {
      self.isFormValid = true;
    } else {
      if (self.modalType == 1) {
        self.list.push(item);
      } else if (self.modalType == 2) {
        self.list.find(function (value, index) {
          if (value.id == item.id) {
            self.list[index] = item;
          }
        });
      } else {
        return;
      }
      self.item = {};
      self.showModal = false;
    }
  },
```

Но её нужно вызвать в другом компоненте( `Modal` ) по клику на коноку:

```
v-on:click="submit(item)"
```

Не могу понять как сделать коммуникацию между двумя компонентами. 
Нашел в [документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8), но пока ума не приложу как это использовать. 
Потому прошу помощи...

Полный код лежит [здесь(кликабельно)](https://bitbucket.org/Swartex/vue-list)

[Примерно что должно получится](http://i93296p9.beget.tech/)

Comment: В документации которую указали, немного не о том. Вам надо понять основы взаимодействия между компонентами. В модалке у Вас форма и props в model binding нельзя указывать. Если проблема актуальна могу небольшой пример где нибудь выложить.

Comment: @АндрейКасьянов буду очень благодарен за пример)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно из модального окна отправить событие при нажатии на кнопку и далее в листе его обработать. Выглядеть это может примерно так:

```
// modal component
v-on:click="$emit('apply')"
```

компонент листа:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="el in list">
      <div @click="openModal(el)">{{el}}</div>
    </div>
    <modal :item="item" v-if="showModal" @apply="submit"></modal>
  </div>
<template>


export default {
  // ...
  data() {
    return { 
      item: {},
      showModal: false
    }
  }
  methods: {
    openModal(item) {
      this.item = item
      this.showModal = true
    },
    submit(item) {
     // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: я просто использую vue-cli, можете подсказать какой там аналог директивы @apply ?

Comment: Это не деректива. В модальном окне вы делаете emit кастомного события apply и далее отлавливаете его в компоненте листа и обрабатываете: @apply="submit"

Comment: Да уже разобрался, спасибо!